# How do you convert Linear Programming Problem into Game Theory Problem?

Tags: game-theory, operations-research, dynamic-programming

Given an objective function and constraints we can solve an LPP using Simplex, Graphical methods but can we convert it into a game theory problem? thus solving the LPP using game theory methods.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.